# Infinitesimal thickening of a smooth closed subscheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra, schemes, noetherian

Let $A$ be a noetherian ring (if it is useful I can assume that $A$ is an algebra of essentially finite type over a field) and $I \subset A$ is an ideal s.t. $A/I$ is smooth. Is it true that extension of algebras
$$
0 \to I/I^2 \to A/I^2 \to A/I \to 0
$$
splits (as a sequence of algebras)? Do I need $A$ to be smooth or $I/I^2$ to be projective?
In other words can we say that infinitesimal thickening of a smooth subscheme is just adding direction in the conormal bundle?

Comment: I just removed a stray "bun" from the first word.

Comment: What do you mean by split sequence of algebras ? $I/I^2$ is not an algebra (in the sense of commutative algebra).

Comment: I mean give a trivial element in the extension group $Ex(A/I, I/I^2)$.

Comment: So you want a splitting as group extension. If $A$ is an algebra over a field, then this is always true because $A/I$ will be free over the field, but this is not very interesting. A strong requirement would be a splitting as $A$-modules, but this holds if and only if $I=I^2$, which is a too strong condition.

Comment: You confusing extension of algebras and extensions of modules. As I say I want it to be trivial in $Ex$ not in $Ext$.

Comment: I apologize beforehand for commenting on such an old question, but my confusion is same as that of Cantlog ... what structures are you considering on the objects of your sequence ? Definitely $I/I^2$ is not an $A$-algebra ... and what do you even mean by $Ex $ ?

Comment: @user It means that there is a splitting map $A/I\to A/I^2$ which is a homomorphism of $k$-algebras.
A hint to the solution: observe that $I/I^2$ is an ideal of square zero in $A/I^2$ and apply the definition of smoothness.